# program calling multiple functions at once keeps crashing. (C programming)

Tags: c, struct

Hi I am currently trying to learn how to program, and I have been mucking around with structs and pointers in C. So I just made this really random rock paper scissors esque program that works partially but will eventually crash after a couple of loops and I have been trying to narrow down the issue to no avail and any insight into this would be much appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
  struct mainChar{

  int hp;
  char name[50];
  int ability;
  int abilitydmg;
  int edefense;
 };
   struct enemyChar{
   int ehp;
   char ename[50];
   int eability;
   int eabilitydmg;
   int edefense;

    };

    typedef struct mainChar mainchar_t;
    typedef struct enemyChar enemychar_t;
    void oppdaternavnMC(mainchar_t *hoved);
    void oppdaterenavnenemy(enemychar_t* hoved);
    void oppdatereability(mainchar_t *angrep);
    void oppdaterehp(enemychar_t *evullief);
    void oppdaterhp(mainchar_t *lief);


    int main(){
    char e;


    int ai;
    int fortsett;
    srand(time(NULL));
    fortsett=1;
    mainchar_t mainchar;
    enemychar_t enemychar;
    mainchar.hp=100;
    enemychar.ehp=100;
    oppdaternavnMC(&mainchar);
    printf("%s is your name!\n", mainchar.name);
    oppdaterenavnenemy(&enemychar);
     printf("%s is your enemys name\n", enemychar.ename);
//1 kick, 2 punch 3 throw
    do{
      oppdatereability(&mainchar);
      ai=(rand()%3)+1;
      if(mainchar.ability==1){
        printf("you kicked!\n");
        //ai=1;
        //ai=(rand()%3)+1;
        if(ai==1){
            printf("you both kicked!\n");
            oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
            oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
            printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n",mainchar.name, mainchar.hp, enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
        }else if(ai==2){
            printf("%s attempts to punch!\n", enemychar.ename);
            oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
            oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
            printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n",mainchar.name, mainchar.hp, enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
        }else if(ai==3){
            printf("%s attempts to throw!\n", enemychar.ehp);
            oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
            oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
            printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n",mainchar.name, mainchar.hp, enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
        }else{
            printf("what");
        }
        }else if(mainchar.ability==2){
        printf("you punched!\n");
        //ai=(rand()%3)+1;
        if(ai==1){
            printf("%s attempts to kick ferociously!\n", enemychar.ehp);
            oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
            oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
            printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n",mainchar.name, mainchar.hp, enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
        }else if(ai==2){
            printf("you both punch!\n", enemychar.ename);
            oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
            oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
            printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n",mainchar.name, mainchar.hp, enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
        }else if(ai<=3){
            printf("%s attempts to throw!", enemychar.ehp);
            oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
            oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
            printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n",mainchar.name, mainchar.hp, enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
        }else{  
            printf("what");

        }


    }else if(mainchar.ability==3){
        printf("you started throwing %s\n", enemychar.ehp);
        //ai=(rand()%5)+1;
        if(ai==1){
            printf("%s started kicking ferociously!\n", enemychar.ehp);
            oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
            oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
            printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n",mainchar.name, mainchar.hp, enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
        }else if(ai==2){
            printf("%s attempts to punch!\n", enemychar.ename);
            oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
            oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
            printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n",mainchar.name, mainchar.hp,  enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
        }else if(ai<=3){
            printf("you both started throwing!", enemychar.ehp);
            oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
            oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
            printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n",mainchar.name, mainchar.hp,        enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
        }else{
            printf("what");
        }


    }



}while(fortsett==1);
if(mainchar.hp==0){
    printf("you lost!");
}else{
    printf("you won!");
}
}



void oppdaterenavnenemy(enemychar_t* hoved){
  char hode[50];
  printf("Enter the name of your enemy: ");
  scanf("%s",&hode );
  strcpy(hoved->ename, hode);
}
void oppdaternavnMC(mainchar_t* hoved){
  char hode[50];
  printf("Enter the name of your character: ");
  scanf("%s",&hode );
  strcpy(hoved->name, hode);
}
void oppdatereability(mainchar_t *angrep){
  int h;
  printf("velg ditt angrep\n 1. kick\n 2.punch\n3.throw\n");
  scanf("%d", &h);
  printf("\n dette er hvilket input some er registrert! %d\n", h);
  angrep->ability=h;
}
void oppdaterhp(mainchar_t *lief){
  int a;
  a=lief->hp-(rand()%20)+1;
  lief->hp=a;

}
void oppdaterehp(enemychar_t *evullief){

  int b;
  b=evullief->ehp-(rand()%20)+1;
  evullief->ehp=b;

}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of different structure types for the main character and enemy characters?  Why is the main character field `edefense` (the same as the enemy) instead of `defense`, which would be consistent with the other names (assuming you keep the two different types, which is probably not warranted).

Answer (score 1):

You have `%s` in `printf()` instead of `%d` several times, too many arguments in other places and `scanf("%s",&hode );` must be `scanf("%s",hode );` every time. Please listen to your compiler if it utters warnings, the compilers is almost always right in that regard.

Here is you code with all the errors I listed above corrected. It has more problems but I'm sure you can solve them yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct mainChar {
  int hp;
  char name[50];
  int ability;
  int abilitydmg;
  int edefense;
};

struct enemyChar {
  int ehp;
  char ename[50];
  int eability;
  int eabilitydmg;
  int edefense;

};

typedef struct mainChar mainchar_t;
typedef struct enemyChar enemychar_t;

void oppdaternavnMC(mainchar_t * hoved);
void oppdaterenavnenemy(enemychar_t * hoved);
void oppdatereability(mainchar_t * angrep);
void oppdaterehp(enemychar_t * evullief);
void oppdaterhp(mainchar_t * lief);

#define START_POWER 100

int main()
{
  int ai;
  int fortsett;
  srand(time(NULL));
  fortsett = 1;
  mainchar_t mainchar;
  enemychar_t enemychar;
  mainchar.hp = START_POWER;
  enemychar.ehp = START_POWER;

  oppdaternavnMC(&mainchar);
  printf("%s is your name!\n", mainchar.name);
  oppdaterenavnenemy(&enemychar);
  printf("%s is your enemys name\n", enemychar.ename);

  //1 kick, 2 punch 3 throw
  do {
    oppdatereability(&mainchar);
    ai = (rand() % 3) + 1;
    if (mainchar.ability == 1) {
      puts("you kicked!");
      //ai=1;
      //ai=(rand()%3)+1;
      if (ai == 1) {
        puts("you both kicked!");
        oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
        oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
        printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n", mainchar.name, mainchar.hp,
               enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
      } else if (ai == 2) {
        printf("%s attempts to punch!\n", enemychar.ename);
        oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
        oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
        printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n", mainchar.name, mainchar.hp,
               enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
      } else if (ai == 3) {
        printf("%d attempts to throw!\n", enemychar.ehp);
        oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
        oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
        printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n", mainchar.name, mainchar.hp,
               enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
      } else {
        printf("what");
      }
    } else if (mainchar.ability == 2) {
      printf("you punched!\n");
      //ai=(rand()%3)+1;
      if (ai == 1) {
        printf("%d attempts to kick ferociously!\n", enemychar.ehp);
        oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
        oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
        printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n", mainchar.name, mainchar.hp,
               enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
      } else if (ai == 2) {
        puts("you both punch!");
        oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
        oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
        printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n", mainchar.name, mainchar.hp,
               enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
      } else if (ai <= 3) {
        printf("%d attempts to throw!", enemychar.ehp);
        oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
        oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
        printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n", mainchar.name, mainchar.hp,
               enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
      } else {
        printf("what");

      }


    } else if (mainchar.ability == 3) {
      printf("you started throwing %d\n", enemychar.ehp);
      //ai=(rand()%5)+1;
      if (ai == 1) {
        printf("%d started kicking ferociously!\n", enemychar.ehp);
        oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
        oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
        printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n", mainchar.name, mainchar.hp,
               enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
      } else if (ai == 2) {
        printf("%s attempts to punch!\n", enemychar.ename);
        oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
        oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
        printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n", mainchar.name, mainchar.hp,
               enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
      } else if (ai <= 3) {
        puts("you both started throwing!");
        oppdaterehp(&enemychar);
        oppdaterhp(&mainchar);
        printf("%s hp: %d\n %s hp: %d\n", mainchar.name, mainchar.hp,
               enemychar.ename, enemychar.ehp);
      } else {
        puts("what");
      }
    }
  } while (fortsett == 1);
  if (mainchar.hp == 0) {
    printf("you lost!");
  } else {
    printf("you won!");
  }
}

void oppdaterenavnenemy(enemychar_t * hoved)
{
  char hode[50];
  int res;
  printf("Enter the name of your enemy: ");
  res = scanf("%49s", hode);
  if(res != 1){
    fprintf(stderr,"scanf in oppdaterenavnenemy() failed\n");
  }
  strcpy(hoved->ename, hode);
}

void oppdaternavnMC(mainchar_t * hoved)
{
  char hode[50];
  int res;
  printf("Enter the name of your character: ");
  res = scanf("%49s", hode);
  if(res != 1){
    fprintf(stderr,"scanf in oppdaternavnMC() failed\n");
  }
  strcpy(hoved->name, hode);
}

void oppdatereability(mainchar_t * angrep)
{
  int h, res;
  printf("velg ditt angrep\n 1. kick\n 2.punch\n3.throw\n");
  res = scanf("%d", &h);
  if(res != 1){
    fprintf(stderr,"scanf in oppdatereability() failed\n");
  }
  printf("\n dette er hvilket input some er registrert! %d\n", h);
  angrep->ability = h;
}

void oppdaterhp(mainchar_t * lief)
{
  int a;
  a = lief->hp - (rand() % 20) + 1;
  lief->hp = a;
}

void oppdaterehp(enemychar_t * evullief)
{
  int b;
  b = evullief->ehp - (rand() % 20) + 1;
  evullief->ehp = b;
}
```